# python poplib.POP3 decrypt base64

Tags: python, base64, pop3, poplib

I'm trying to download all emails from pop3 into a text file with this python code:

```
def Download(pop3,username,password):
try:
    Mailbox = poplib.POP3(pop3, '110') 
    Mailbox.user(username) 
    Mailbox.pass_(password) 
    numMessages = len(Mailbox.list()[1])
    for i in range(numMessages):
        logfile = open(username + '.log', 'a')                    
        logfile.write('\n')                    
        for msg in Mailbox.retr(i+1)[1]:
            print msg                   
            logfile.write('%s\n' % (msg))                    
        logfile.close()
    Mailbox.quit()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print 'Exit'
    sys.exit(1)
```

My problem is the email is encrypted in base64,
how I can call only email body for decryption?

```
base64.b64decode(body)
```

Comment: It's an "encoding", not an "encryption".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [`email`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email)-package to parse emails. The [`get_payload`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.get_payload)-method on the parsed message object can handle the decoding for you when using the `decode=True` argument.

For a simple (non-multipart) message, it would look something like this:

```
import email.parser
...
parser = email.parser.FeedParser()
for msg in Mailbox.retr(i+1)[1]:
    parser.feed(msg + '\n')
message = parser.close()
payload = message.get_payload(decode=True)
print(payload)
...
```

Comment: numMessages = len(Mailbox.list()[1])
  for i in range(numMessages):
   parser = email.parser.FeedParser()
   for msg in Mailbox.retr(i+1)[1]:
    parser.feed(msg + '\n')
   message = parser.close()
   payload = message.get_payload(decode=True)
   print(payload)
  Mailbox.quit()
 
im edit my script bat not working ... 
  File "c:\GetMails.py", line 17, in Download
    parser = email.parser.FeedParser()
NameError: global name 'email' is not defined

Comment: what is name of package import ?
im try : Import parser 
and not working teh script.

Comment: `import email.parser`. I've already updated my answer to include that line before...

Answer (score 1):

Try the following on your text:

```
import base64

base64.decodestring(string_to_decode)
```

As an example:

```
In [1]: import base64

In [2]: base64.encodestring("alpha beta gamma")
Out[2]: 'YWxwaGEgYmV0YSBnYW1tYQ==\n'

In [3]: test = base64.encodestring("alpha beta gamma")

In [4]: base64.decodestring(test)
Out[4]: 'alpha beta gamma'
```

In your case, you should have:

```
msg = base64.decodestring(msg)
logfile.write('%s\n' % (msg))
```

Just pay attention to what is `msg`; if it is not a base64 string, you should split the result so that you get the base64 encoded part you want.